# Magento2 Update layout Using Observer on Product page

Tags: magento2, layout, event-observer, theme, product-page

I want to Update XML using observer on Product Page when page load.
I want to set there condition with product Attribute there.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you can do is add layout via event layout_load_before, you can use this event to add your dynamic layout.

Here is sample code for you.

> step: 1 create events.xml in your module

[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <!-- for diffrentiate layout.xml on product basis -->
        <event name="layout_load_before">
            <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

> Step:2 Now create observer `LayoutLoadBefore.php`

In your [Vendor][Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore.php file write below code

```
    <?php

    namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

    class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
         */
        protected $_registry;

        public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        )
        {
            $this->_registry = $registry;
        }


        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');

            if (!$product){
              return $this;
            }
            if($product->getSku() =='product_sku'){ // add your multiple attribute condition
               $layout = $observer->getLayout();
               $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view_customlayout'); 
// here you will have to set custom layout which is for specific layout.
            }

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

> Step 3: Create layout file for custom layout.

Create layout file in your custom theme/ custom module.

> **[Theme]/frontend/Magento_catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_customlayout.xml**

or

> **[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_customlayout.xml**

and write your code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        ...
            //write your custm code here.
        ...
    </body>
</page>
```

This file only rendered in your specific condition of products.

now in this file you can add your special requirements.

Hope this will help you !..

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use an observer to be honest, but a plugin.

Wrap it around `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View`.

Something like this:

```
class AroundHelperProductView
{
    public function aroundinitProductLayout(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject, 
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage, 
        $product, 
        $params = null
    ) {

        $result = $proceed($resultPage, $product, $params);

        $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['attribute' => 'value'], 'catalog_product_view');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

That way you get a `catalog_product_view_attribute_value.xml` definition that you can fill with whatever you need. Be aware that `attribute` and `value` in the filename are dependent on what you place in the Plugin. Optionally you can loop through the different values from an attribute and add a handle for each unique value.

*Update: Noticed I forgot the handle after the params in the function call.*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Observer you can use **Plugin**(interceptors) concept.By using before, after and around methods you can manipulate your layout.

for example : in any block we have **getChildHtml($alias = '', $useCache = true)**. for this one you can make

```
public function beforeGetChildHtml(/* your source class */ $subject,$alias = '', $useCache = true)
{
    $layout = $subject->getLayout();

    if (!$layout) {
        return '';
    }
    $childName = $layout->getChildName($subject->getNameInLayout(), $alias);
    if (!$childName) {
        return '';
    }
    if($childName=="/*your block name */")
    {
        addchild to your block
    }
}
```

Same way you can use after and around as per your requirement

read devdocs for more information
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html