# Magento 2.2.5: How to remove links on my account navigation by php code?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, link

What's up guys, I'm looking for how to remove links on "My Account" page in magento 2 with PHP code.


So i've searched a lot and only saw this layout xml solution:
[How to add/remove links on my account navigation magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91648/how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation-magento2)

But what i want is do it by PHP code, because i have some special condition, for example, when customer is in wholesale group, then the "My order" is hiding.

The check customer part is an easy part and i've done it, but not with the "hiding my order" part

Any idea? Please help, thanks :)
[image]
[image]

Comment: you can remove whole sidebar and create custom sidebar then after you can do whatever you want.

Comment: you can try plugin

Comment: @AasimGoriya that sound cool but won't be the best practice :) I hope to find another way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

create this file `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` with below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_element_link" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\LinksPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `LinksPlugin.php` file in `/Vendor/Module/Plugin/` with below cpntent.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


class LinksPlugin
{
    public function afterRenderLink(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links $subject, $result, \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $link)
    {
        if($link->getNameInLayout()=='customer-account-navigation-account-link')
        {
            $result = "";
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: wow, thanks, i'll try this and feedback to you later :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create observer for event **layout_render_before_customer_account** and add logic that necessary to your requirements.

Example how to create Observer located here  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/228406/43911

Comment: thanks for replying, but if i use observer, then how to hide the "My Order" (which is the links that i want to hiding)?